# Stata Scatter Sort by Y-Axis

Tags: stata

I want to plot the average weight (y-axis) by make (x-axis) and sort it so the heaviest make is the leftmost on the x-axis and the lightest is the rightmost on the x-axis. I thought the `sort` option would work.

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if foreign
sort mpg 
gen obsno = _n 
scatter weight obsno, xla(1/22) sort(weight)
```

Comment: The `sort()` option affects graph commands like "line" and not 
scatter", AFAIK. Why do you have `sort mpg` in line 3 instead of `gsort -weight`, which is what might give you the results you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort()` option is allowed with `scatter` because one of the possibilities of `scatter` is to connect points with a line. But it refers only to the order in which points are connected. The default is to connect points in the current sort order of the dataset. In practice the most common example is that observations are in some time order or follow some other sequence but even then `scatter` would respect the order of a time or other variable only if the data were in the same order -- unless, to complete the circle, a sort order were specified with this option.

You are not asking for any connnection. In that circumstance, `sort()` remains legal but it is ignored as of no relevance to what you're asking for.

There is no circumstance in which `sort()` has another effect with `scatter` and it will not change either axis variable to something else.

A way to get what I think you want is with the undocumented `vertical` option of `graph dot`. Some of the small choices here are just my personal idea of what looks good. For example, I have found that the default dotted grid lines often copy poorly to other software, so I use thin light grey continuous lines as a grid.

```
sysuse auto, clear
keep if foreign
sort mpg 
gen obsno = _n 
graph dot (asis) weight, over(obsno, sort(1) descending) vertical ///
linetype(line) lines(lcolor(gs12) lw(vthin)) yla(, ang(h))
```

[image]

It's perfectly possible to get a similar graph using `scatter`, just more work as you have to arrange that the observation numbers become the value labels of a variable defining the sort order.

See also `quantile` and `qplot` (*Stata Journal*).

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, is it possible using `graph dot` to connect the minimum and maximum weight by make with the dot representing the avg?

Comment: No; `graph dot` doesn't allow connections. You're back to `scatter`, although I don't have a clear idea of exactly what you want. For example,  no dot in the plot shown represents the average except by accident.